# Cohomology of Stiefel manifolds

Tags: homology-cohomology, complex-geometry, stiefel-manifolds

Define the complex Stiefel space $W_{n,k}$ as $U(n)/U(k)$. What is its (co)homology? (Either singular or de Rham).

I've searched through a bunch of classical references but can't seem to find this information anywhere. I'd be over the moon with either a reference, or even just a sketch proof.

Edit: Quite a few papers seem to refer to specific facts without giving any reference. For instance, I have seen statements such as $H_{2k+1}(W_{n,k};\mathbb{Z})\cong\mathbb{Z}$, but with no real explanation as to why this is true. This leads me to believe that the (co)homology of these complex Stiefel spaces is classically well-known, but I can't seem to find *where*.

Comment: Viewing $W$ as the set of tuples $(v_1,\dots,v_k)$ of orthonormal vectors, there is a projection onto the last componnt. That is a fibration with fiber a sphere and fiber a smaller Stieffel manifold. Have you tried to obtain a recursive decription of the cohomology using this?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I haven't, no. I'm just about to update the question with some extra information actually.

Comment: I don't have it in front of me, but I'm pretty sure this is in Fuchs' Topology II.  Also, almost any paper of Bob Stong's would contain this calculation.  Maybe try his Notes on Cobordism Theory.

Comment: @Randall Yes! It's Theorem III.3.2.A, p. 218. Thank you. Do you want to post this as an answer so that I can accept it? Save anybody else from searching in all the wrong places.

Comment: Ha, sure.  Glad I could help.

Comment: Can add the precise reference in my answer.  Did you find it in Fuchs or Stong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per OP's request:

I don't have it in front of me, but I'm pretty sure this is in Fuchs' Topology II. Also, almost any paper of Bob Stong's would contain this calculation. Maybe try his Notes on Cobordism Theory.

Found in:  Fuchs and Viro's **Topology II**, Theorem III.3.2.A, page 218 (Springer).

Comment: It is, and it's Theorem III.3.2.A, p. 218

Answer (score 2):

See pages 301-302 of Hatcher's Algebraic Topology for some partial results.

Comment: This is great thanks. I didn't realise that this was in Hatcher, and it seems quite clear, so if it comes down to it then I will try using this as a way of calculating the homology myself!